# Shrink image in navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an image in the navigation bar that is a little too large and overlaps beyond the nav bar. I want to scale the image down to fit inside the bar. The code I have now is:

```
let banner = UIImage(named: "banner.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:banner)
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

But the ScaleAspectFit doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: I updated my issue by adding a frame:

```
let banner = UIImage(named: "banner.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:banner)
var bannerWidth = navigationItem.titleView!.frame.width
var bannerHeight = navigationItem.titleView!.frame.height
var bannerx = navigationItem.titleView!.frame.size.width / 2 - banner!.size.width / 2
var bannery = navigationItem.titleView!.frame.size.height / 2 - banner!.size.height / 2       
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerx, y: bannery, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

But am now getting the error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

On the bannerWidth variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

> But the ScaleAspectFit doesn't seem to work

Sure it works. The problem is that you have not provided any scale for it to scale *to*. You have not given `imageView` a `frame`. Therefore it is the size of the original image, which is too big. As you say yourself, you need to scale it down. Either scale the image view by giving it a `frame`, or scale the image by drawing it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Was using the wrong navigation code

```
let banner = UIImage(named: "banner.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:banner)
var bannerWidth = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width
var bannerHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height
var bannerx = bannerWidth! / 2 - banner!.size.width / 2
var bannery = bannerHeight! / 2 - banner!.size.height / 2
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerx, y: bannery, width: bannerWidth!, height: bannerHeight!)
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Answer (score 0):

To resize the image try modifying the navigationItem.titleView's constraints, it works for me.

```
let banner = UIImage(named: "banner")
let bannerView = UIImageView(image: banner)
bannerView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
self.navigationItem.titleView = bannerView
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.navigationItem.titleView!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22),self.navigationItem.titleView!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128)])
```